# How can i count loop and set value in a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to transpose 1 row into Multiple row or record to Create BOM Structure for an Assembly Item Some have 3 Component/Item the other have 2,1 or more.

When I run this script It takes the last INSERT Query to create a record if Assembly has only one component . On the  attached Image on the first record highlighted in yellow - the bomEntry Field Should show 1 instead of 3 because it has only one Component.

If Assembly have two BOMs, Let say Assembly A has Components A1 and A2. It should be displayed as

```
    Item   PartiD  bomEntry
    A      A1      1
    A      A2      2
```

Currently when insert my data in a table looks like this. 
[image]

```
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table1 (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES ($itemid, $bom1,'1','A','1')");
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table1 (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES ($itemid, $bom2,'1','A','2')");
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table1 (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES ($itemid, $bom3,'1','A','3')");
```

How can i count Number of Component and Set `bomEntry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable that you increment between each `INSERT` query. Also, use a prepared query instead of substituting variables.

Before inserting each component, check whether the component actually exists in the record.

```
$stmt = myqsli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO table1 (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES (?, ?,'1','A',?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iii", $itemid, $bom, $bomEntry) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$recordd = $tv->search(30008475847254898, 's=2'); 
foreach($recordd as $data2) { 
    $itemid = $data2['fields']['CALC STOCK NO']; 

    $bomEntry = 1;
    if ($data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN']) {
        $bom = $data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN']; 
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
        $bomEntry++;
    }
    if ($data2['fields']['BOM TIRE PN']) {
        $bom = $data2['fields']['BOM TIRE PN'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
        $bomEntry++;
    }
    if ($data2['fields']['BOM VALVE PN']) {
        $bom = $data2['fields']['BOM VALVE PN'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
        $bomEntry++;
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot but in the sorce table all BOM listed in row `A, BOM1, BOM2, BOM3...` thats is why i used three Insert Statement to Transpose single row to multiple row

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do the insert inside that loop.

Comment: Thanks again sets  `bomEntry` 3 instead 1 for the Assembly with 1 BOM/Component

Comment: sorry i run the old script

Comment: Its not adding anything May be i miss something here is the code i used

Comment: Code in comments is really difficult to read. Is that the same as my code?

Comment: I've added error checking in my answer. Try that version and let me know if there are any errors.

Comment: That probably means a syntax error, check your PHP error log.

Comment: There was an extra parenthesis after `INSERT INTO tablename`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar i should get fix this is the right code but i still didn't get the issue i Can print `$recordd` (`print_r($recorded`))before your code but doesnt print inside and above the 'foreach` and what does `iii` does?

Comment: `iii` means that the values being substituted into the query are integers. Can't you read the documentation? Don't you like to understand the code instead of just copying it blindly?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time There were a typo on your code `$stmt = myqsli_prepare($con,` BUT after i fix that the code is doing the same as mine. For example if you see the image on my question 600199 has one BOM but `bomEntry` shows `3` while it suppose to be `1` thats is my main reason to post this question.

Comment: I don't understand. For each `$itemid`, it should enter 3 rows with a `partid` that comes from `$data2` and `bomEntry` should count up starting from 1.

Comment: First  codes `$bom = $data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN'];` adds 500series BOM number, 2nd `$bom = $data2['fields']['BOM TIRE PN'];` adds 200 series BOM, Last one the 3rd code add 100 series. `$bomEntry=1` start 1 and Increment by one and the Assembly 600199 has one BOM which is 100199 series

Comment: When it adds `BOM WHEEL PN` that gets `bomEntry = 1`. When it adds `BOM TIRE PN` that gets `bomEntry = 2`. When it adds `BOM VALVE PN` that gets `bomEntry = 3`.

Comment: In the question you said some items only have 1 or 2 components. How do you know which ones those are?

Comment: if there is any way to add conditional statement if `BOM WHEEL PN=" " ` same for other skip the increment  or count?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a check first before inserting each component. Then it only increments `$bomEntry` if that component exists.

Comment: Thats what am talking about!! Thanks alot!!